# failed to install hdf5r

Tags: r, seurat, software-installation, rstudio

I failed to install hdf5r using this command provided by https://satijalab.org/seurat/mca_loom.html: devtools::install_github(repo = 'hhoeflin/hdf5r'),below is the code,can you help me ?
[image]

[image]

[image]